# ksqldb iso8601 datetime format return null

Tags: confluent-platform, confluence, ksqldb

Hello i have varchar column with datetime.

its utc

```
|2022-02-09T13:27:17.165116Z
|2022-02-09T13:27:27.3850848Z
|2022-02-09T13:28:18.5537284Z
```

on select query parse as by standart but return 'null' for all rows:

```
PARSE_TIMESTAMP(entrydate, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ')
```

code:

```
JsonSerializer.Serialize(DateTime.UtcNow);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because ksqldb only supports up to millisecond precision see https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksqldb-2-0-introduces-date-and-time-data-types/

There is a github issue tracking support for finer time resolution like microseconds here https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/8243

Comment: what is crazy.... what i can do for work now ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your DateFormat, `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ` which expects a precision of milliseconds but, from your input, it's microseconds.

To cover all the scenarios (as you are serializing it with `JsonSerializer.Serialize`, and it can happen that you don't even have anything after the seconds, or, milliseconds is zero: `2022-02-09T13:28:18Z`) you would need to use the following format:

`'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss[.SSSSSSS][.SSSSSS][.SSSSS][.SSSS][.SSS][.SS][.S]''Z'''`
This will cover all the use cases with/without the milliseconds/microseconds precision

More about the formatting:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html
So we use the following formatting options to specify that the precision is optional:

```
[  optional section start 
]  optional section end
```

and

```
S       fraction-of-second          fraction          978
```

note that you also have to 'escape' the letters:
https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/create-stream/#timestamp_format

Possible improvement (give it a try):
`PARSE_TIMESTAMP(entrydate, 'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss[.SSSSSSS][.SSSSSS][.SSSSS][.SSSS][.SSS][.SS][.S]X', 'UTC')`
(you have to specify `timezone` so that it can parse the `X` to a correct timestamp including the zone)

from the Java `DateTimeFormatter` docs:

> Pattern letter 'X' (upper case) will output 'Z' when the offset to be output would be zero, whereas pattern letter 'x' (lower case) will output '+00', '+0000', or '+00:00'.